# Is it possible to have a user input to a sort

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have a SQL query and how it sort by user input from a textbox, what I am trying to do is get all the records from a table by the date from the user input

```
SELECT  orderDate AS Date, orderPizzaTotals AS 'PIZZAS SOLD', 
        orderDrinkTotals AS 'DRINKS SOLD', 
        orderPriceTotal AS 'TRANSACTION TOTAL' 
FROM dbo.[Order] sort "USERINPUT.TEXT"
```

Comment: What are you using for the textbox? PHP? C#? Java? Well in that program, get the content of that text box and concatenate it with the sql query, then execute that query. **BUT** if the syntax is invalid the query will fail. Instead of a text box consider a drop-down of sorting options, or clicking on a heading, or some other device which protects you from garbage and/or sql injection.

Comment: Post the type of database server. You can certainly do this in SQL Server but it's not recommended. In SQL Server you could use `OPENROWSET` to open the text file on the fly, then use a  `case` statement to select to field to order by

Comment: How will the user know the name of the column to sort?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to sort based on dynamic information (e.g. a parameter you pass from the code) if you use dynamic SQL in SQL Server:

```
declare @userinput nvarchar(100) = 'your_column'

declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = N'SELECT  orderDate AS Date, 
    orderPizzaTotals AS ''PIZZAS SOLD'', 
    orderDrinkTotals AS ''DRINKS SOLD'', 
    orderPriceTotal AS ''TRANSACTION TOTAL'' FROM dbo.[Order] 
    ORDER BY ' + @userinput

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: hmm I was not aware of this I should try it !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a giant case statement:

```
SELECT  orderDate AS Date, orderPizzaTotals AS "PIZZAS SOLD", 
        orderDrinkTotals AS "DRINKS SOLD", 
        orderPriceTotal AS "TRANSACTION TOTAL"
FROM dbo.[Order] o
ORDER BY (case when USERINPUT.TEXT = 'Date' then Date end),
         (case when USERINPUT.TEXT = 'PIZZAS SOLD' then "PIZZAS SOLD" end),
         (case when USERINPUT.TEXT = 'DRINKS SOLD' then "DRINKS SOLD" end),
         (case when USERINPUT.TEXT = 'TRANSACTION TOTAL' then "TRANSACTION TOTAL" end)
```

The reason for using separate `case` statements is to handle the fact that the columns might have different types.